# Inserting logo in Master asp page at the bottom right corner does not work when scrolling: overlaps

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have an asp.net webform app.

It consists on a master page and a web form.

I am trying to insert a logo at the bottom right corner of the master page, it works but when scrolling logo overlaps on the page body.

Web form Default.aspx contains an html table in the contentplaceholder1.

In the Default.Master I have tried below:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.master.cs" Inherits="MyTool.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/MySite.css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  EnableCdn="true"> <%-- To retrieve the jQuery files from CDN we enable EnableCdn --%>
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div class="logo-img">
                <img id="myLogo" src="Images/myLogo.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**In My MySite.css file I have below class**:

```
.logo-img {
    position: absolute; // also I have tried fixed and the same occurs
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Initially when web form loads:

[image]

But when scrolling is used this does not work, the logo overlaps the page body and also the table in Default.aspx. See below screenshot:

[image]

Also I have tried to change position in the css, I have replaced absolute to fixed and I get the same results. I do not want logo to overlap on the table and on any object in the page body.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the position property here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, it'll explain why you're seeing that scrolling effect for position: absolute. Maybe try position: relative instead, if you want to move it to the right without impacting other elements on the page.

Comment: Using position: relative makes logo avoid overlapping but logo is then placed at the bottom left corner instead of at the bottom right corner.

Comment: You can try using align or margin to shift it to the right, once you have it set as relative.

Comment: I have set it to absolute and then I have used z-index property set to -1 so logo is always placed correctly at the bottom right corner even when scrolling.When scrolling logo overlaps but not over the components (table, etc) on the body, it keeps in background as part of it and it is good for me. I must say that in this case using z-index, relative behaves the same as absolute, no difference between using one or another.